# Scrapy - merging results from N pages originating from single page

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm scraping a webpage with information about a course. The page also has links to evaluation pages, one for each year, so there's a **1-to-N relationship**. I have a method for parsing the main page and a method to parse the evaluation page. The first method calls the second method for each link found.

My question is, where should I return the Item object?

```
def parse_course(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    main_div = select_single(hxs, '//div[@class = "CourseViewer"]/div[@id = "pagecontents"]')
    course = CourseItem()
    # here I scrape basic info about the item
    self.process_heading(main_div, course)
    grades_table = select_single(hxs, '//td[@class = "ContentMain"]//table[contains(tr/td/b/text(), "Grades")]')
    grade_links = grades_table.select('tr[2]/td[2]/a/@href').extract()
    for link in grade_links:
        yield Request(link, callback = self.parse_grade_dist_page, meta = {'course' : course})

def parse_grade_dist_page(self, response):
    course = response.meta['course']
    # scrape additional data and store it in CourseItem
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many approaches, here are a few:

1. You could keep track of the requests made and return the item when is the last request. This might be hard as you have to handle the case when the request fails.
2. You could perform each request one after another in a linear fashion. Also you will have to handle the case when the request fails and continue with the others.
3. You could use [scrapy-inline-requests](https://github.com/darkrho/scrapy-inline-requests):

   ```
   @inline_requests
   def parse_course(self, response):

       # ...

       for link in grade_links:
           try:
               response = yield Request(link)
           except Exception as e:
               # handle the exception here
               pass
           else:
               # extract the data here
               pass

        # at the end yield the item
   ```